# How to convert a date string into month day year time

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to convert this date string "2023-11-10T11:00:00" into two variables, one containing the date and one containing the day and time. Something like this:

```
const date = "Nov 10, 2023";
const time = "Saturday 11:00 AM";
```

How could I write a function to do this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The best for you is to use javascript's most use date libraries: moment.js or date-fns. They are much better than regular js date handling.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira if this is all they need to do, I would strongly advise against using a library for something so simple. Also, moment.js is deprecated, no one should be using it in new projects. Even the moment.js official website suggests using other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript's toLocaleString and toLocaleTimeString Date methods.

```
const isoDate = "2023-11-10T11:00:00";
const dateObject = new Date(isoDate); 
const date = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'})
const time = dateObject.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {weekday: 'long', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
```

`date` will end up being `Nov 10, 2023`, and `time` will end up being `Friday 11:00 AM`. 10th is the Friday, not Saturday, as mentioned in your question.